# Is there any geometric and intuitive interpretation of Newton-like iterative steps in numerical optimization?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, na.numerical-analysis

Are the iterative steps in optimization affected by the intrinsic and extrinsic curvatures of the objective functions ? and How?

Is there any geometric and intuitive demo show illustrating the direction and modulus of such iterative steps as Newton-like methods and steepest descent and conjugate gradient methods?

Comment: This is a better question for Google than for MathOverflow.

Comment: thank you! `Google` and `youtube` sometimes don't work for me due to `GFW`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe these images will help?

---

[image]

 
 
 
<sub>(Image by Ruye Wang at [this link](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/NM/node20.html).)</sub>

---

[image: ZigZagging]
 
 
 
<sub>(Image at [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Examples).)</sub>

---

If you prefer dynamic illustrations, there is [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3pVVBK09ow):

 
 
 [image: YouTubeGradient]

Comment: thank you very much! How do you obtain such impressive images?